# Need to hide the filter section in report

Tags: visualforce, reporting

[image]I need to hide the filter section it will not be shown while generating the report how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There is an idea for this : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000a2j8AAA . However, I'm wondering... maybe if you are handy with jQuery you could make a home sidebar component that would set the filter to hidden. Not sure if it's possible though and it would be a quite hacky solution.